Disabled man feeds and spares the life of the bear who attacked him and caused his injury
I rented this DVD back in 2006 or 2007. Hollywood, color, English.
There are two friends (an African American and a Caucasian) live together. The african american is disabled and uses a wheel chair. His friend helps him and care for him a lot. 
At one scene, the disabled man asks his friend to purchase/obtain meat in order to feed a roaming free brown bear. He does, although reluctantly, bring the meat and I remember an other character suggest mixing the meat with honey, because bears love honey.
The man gives the meat to the bear and has the chance to shoot it dead, but he does not. Out of respect to the wish of his disabled friend.
It is later revealed that the bear had attacked the african american and caused his injury/disablement. 
I don't know what motive did the injured man had to ask for sparing the life of the animal who altered his life forever. I can't remember if the movie answers this question or not.

This is Lasse Hallstrom's An Unfinished life from 2005.

To escape an abusive boyfriend, without announcing her plans in advance, Jean Gilkyson takes her young daughter Griff to the Wyoming ranch of her father-in-law, Einar. Jean and Einar are disaffected, as he blames her for the death of his son in a car accident. Einar is taking care of his friend Mitch, who was attacked by a bear, and Einar does not know that he has a granddaughter. While Mitch heals and forgives the bear, Einar also changes his feelings regarding Jean, finally understanding that accidents happen and accepting her and loving Griff.

It starred Robert Redford and Jennifer Lopez, and Morgan Freeman played the handicapped Mitch, who finally decides to set the bear free. Here's the trailer:




You have the most encyclopedic knowledge of most movies. I wonder how you did it. .All I could remember was the bear and the two friends. I totally forgot about the mother and her daughter. Well done, as usual.
